# Android Studio emulator API level incorrect

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, android-virtual-device

[image: window, displayed when I try run app on emulator]

I try to run app on emulator, created by AVD manager, but "Device chooser" says, that emulator API(sdk) version is 1.

What's a trouble? Trying to google for any troubleshooting of my problem, but unsuccessfully.
Any help, please!

Android Studio version 1.5.1

Comment: Is the AVD running normally with developer options enabled? version 1 is reported when adb has no connection to the device

Comment: forget about the standard emulator. install https://www.genymotion.com

Comment: Tim, what mean "AVD developer options"? If you say about this options http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html  , my avd running with options "-netdelay none -netspeed full"

Comment: which android version did you choose for your emulator?

Comment: Gabriele, Api v 23, like in name of emulator